# What causes partitions to be mounted at boot?

Tags: debian, mount, boot, automount, debian-wheezy

I'm upgrading machines from Debian Squeeze to Wheezy. I do all the setup with FAI - disks, packaging, everything. So they come up ready for production. Its all good.

One particular machine has two extra ext4 partitions for database storage. FAI is configured to give them labels, in this case MAINDB and LOGDB. They are not listed in fstab. There are no dirs in /mnt. But somehow on boot, mountpoints are being created and they're being mounted:

```
/dev/sda5  125386396  60984 118949488  1% /mnt/MAINDB
/dev/sdb1  470033332  71664 446078636  1% /mnt/LOGDB
```

Does anyone know what's doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically those can be mounted by anything that is run during system startup. Have you grepped for `MAINDB` and `LOGDB` under `/etc`? Are you running automounter (autofs)?

Comment: Yes, I've done the grep. There's no mention of it anywhere. No, not running any kind of automounter.

Comment: Have you grepped for `/mnt'` ? Maybe there's a udev rule that automatically mounts found partitions under `/mnt`. Usually the rules I've seen have been for mounting under `/media`

Comment: Yeah, udev is where I'm looking now. Nothing so simple as `/mnt`, but the timing indicates that's where its coming up. udev is really hard to debug though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd

```
blkid
```

and grep for the resulting UUID in the `/etc` directory, as `blkid` gives you the UUID of partitions, used even by udev to mount them.

So inspect into `/etc/udev/rules.d` to find if something persistent have been autocreated.